# What is the meaning of the ANTLR syntax in this grammar file?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse a file using ANTLR4 via Python. I am following a tutorial (https://faun.pub/introduction-to-antlr-python-af8a3c603d23); I am able to execute the code and get responses like the ones shown in the tutorial, but I'm failing to understand the logic of the grammar file.

```
grammar MyGrammer;
expr: left=expr op=('*'|'/') right=expr        # InfixExpr
    | left=expr op=('+'|'-') right=expr        # InfixExpr
    | atom=INT                                 # NumberExpr
    | '(' expr ')'                             # ParenExpr 
    | atom=HELLO                               # HelloExpr
    | atom=BYE                                 # ByeExpr
    ;


HELLO: ('hello'|'hi')  ;
BYE  : ('bye'| 'tata') ;
INT  : [0-9]+         ;
WS   : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

From my understanding, The constants (what I call them since they are all capitals) HELLO, BYE, INT, and WS define rules for what that set of text can contain. I think they are relating to functions somehow, but I am not sure. So the HELLO function will be executed if the parser encounters something that says either 'hello' or 'hi'. The expr is what is confusing me.

```
expr: left=expr op=('*'|'/') right=expr        # InfixExpr
    | left=expr op=('+'|'-') right=expr        # InfixExpr
    | atom=INT                                 # NumberExpr
    | '(' expr ')'                             # ParenExpr 
    | atom=HELLO                               # HelloExpr
    | atom=BYE                                 # ByeExpr
    ;


HELLO: ('hello'|'hi')  ;
BYE  : ('bye'| 'tata') ;
INT  : [0-9]+         ;
WS   : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

When I run the command

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammer.g4 -visitor -o dist
```

it produces many files but the main one contains `InfixExpr`, `NumberExpr`, `ParenExpr`, `HelloExpr`, and `ByeExpr`. I can see that somehow the author knows that he is doing something with the constants `HELLO`, `BYE`, etc. Is there any documentation on the `expr` piece above and what do the keywords `atom`, `left`, `right` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Any rules that begin with a capital letter (often we captilize the entire rule name to make it obvious) is a Lexer rule.

Rules that begin with lower case letters are parser rules.

It’s VERY important to understand the difference and the flow of your input all the way through to a parse tree.

Your input stream of characters is first processed by the Lexer (using the Lexer rules) to produce a stream of tokens for the parser to act upon.  It’s important to understand that the parser has NO impact on how the Lexer interprets the input.

When multiple Lexer rules could match you input, two “tie breakers” come into play.

1 - if a rules matches more characters in your input stream than other rules, then that will be the rules used to produce a token.
2 - if there is a tie of multiple Lexer rules matching the same sequence of input characters, then the Lexer rules that appears first in your grammar will be used to generate a token.

Your parser rules are evaluated using a recursive descent approach beginning with whatever startRule you specify.  ANTLR uses several techniques to do it’s best to recognize your input, that includes trying alternatives until one is found that matches, ignoring a token (and producing an error) if that allows the parser to continue on, and inserting a missing token (and producing an error) if that allows the parser to continue.

re: the `expr` portion:

The rule says that there are 6 possible ways to recognize an `expr`

- `left=expr op=('*'|'/') right=expr`  (which will create an InfixExprContext node in the parse tree)
- `left=expr op=('+'|'-') right=expr` (InfixExprContext (also))
- `atom=INT` (NumberExprContext)
- `'(' expr ')'` (ParenExprContext)
- `atom=HELLO` (HelloExprContext)
- `atom=BYE` (ByeExprContext)

The benefit of the labels (ex:  `# InfixExpr`) is that, by creating a Context more specific than an `ExprContext`) you will have `visitInfixExpr`, `visitNumberExpr`, (etc.) methods that you can override in you `Visitor` instead of just a `visitExpr` method that contains all the alternatives.  A similar thing will result for the `enterXX` and `exitXX` methods for your Listener classes.

In the `left=expr op=('*'|'/') right=expr` rule, the `left`, `op` and `right` names will generate accessors that make it easier to access those parts of you parse tree in you `*Context` class (without them you'd just have an array of `expr`, for example and expr[0] would be the first `expr` and `expr[1]` would be the second.  (It's probably a good idea to look at the generated code with and without the names and labels to see the difference.  Both make it MUCH easier to write the logic in your visitor/listeners.

Comment: what specifically is the "expr" portion saying?